# Is there any way to make a running process in D state or Z state?

Tags: linux, process

I am currently testing our software against certain fault injections. Now I am having trouble making a running systemd daemon process in D state or Z state. Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

To create a "D" state process :

```
sudo cat $(mount | awk '$3 == "/" { print $1 }') > /dev/null
# Then run "top" command,
# Sometimes, you'll see "cat" process in "D" state, most of the time in "R" state
```

To create a "Z" state process, create a program with following C code (zombie.c):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main ()
{
  pid_t child_pid;

  child_pid = fork ();
  if (child_pid > 0) {
    sleep (60);
  }
  else {
    exit (0);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Then

```
gcc -o zombie zombie.c
./zombie
```

Comment: Handy way to create D state processes for testing! Came in use while trying out "echo w > /proc/sysrq-trigger"

Answer (score 0):

While the other answer does give a way to create D state processes, it's not reliable, and the process will repeatedly enter and exit D state. On Linux, a more reliable way to do this is using `vfork` (see [this article](https://chrisdown.name/2024/02/05/reliably-creating-d-state-processes-on-demand.html) for more information about how that works). As an example:

```c
#include <unistd.h>

__attribute__((noinline)) static void run_child(void)
{
    pause();
    _exit(0);
}

int main(void)
{
    pid_t pid = vfork();

    if (pid == 0) {
        run_child();
    } else if (pid < 0) {
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

`__attribute__((noinline))` is a good idea in order to make sure that the stack space used in the child is separate from the stack space used by the parent. By preventing inlining, we ensure that the function creates a distinct stack frame on entry, and in the context of the `vfork()e`d child, this means that any stack manipulation occurs neatly in a separate frame, and not in the parent's stack frame. Without it, the compiler may perform optimisations that result in interleaved data between the parent and child, which could result in stack corruption when the parent resumes.

This will then enter D state until a terminal signal is sent:

```bash
% cc -o dstate dstate.c
% ./dstate & sleep 0.1; ps -o pid,state,cmd -p "$!"
[1] 780629
    PID S CMD
 780629 D ./dstate
% kill "$!"
[1]  + terminated  ./dstate
```

(The other answer by Philippe already has a good solution for Z state processes, so I'll omit answering that part again.)